# Golang - ToUpper() on a single byte?

Tags: go, byte, uppercase, lowercase

I have a `[]byte`, `b`, and I want to select a single byte, `b[pos]` and change it too upper case (and then lower case) The `bytes` type has a method called `ToUpper()`. How can I use this for a single byte?

### Calling `ToUpper` on single Byte

OneOfOne gave the most efficient (when calling thousands of times), I use

```
val = byte(unicode.ToUpper(rune(b[pos])))
```

in order to find the byte and change the value

```
b[pos] = val
```

### Checking if byte is Upper

Sometimes, instead of changing the case of a byte, I want to **check if a byte is upper or lower case**; All the upper case roman-alphabet bytes are *lower than the value* of the lower case bytes.

```
func (b Board) isUpper(x int) bool {
    return b.board[x] < []byte{0x5a}[0]
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For a single byte/rune, you can use [`unicode.ToUpper`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#ToUpper).

```
b[pos] = byte(unicode.ToUpper(rune(b[pos])))
```

Answer (score 6):

I want to remind OP that `bytes.ToUpper()` operates on unicode code points encoded using UTF-8 in a byte slice while `unicode.ToUpper()` operates on a single unicode code point.

By asking to convert a single byte to upper case, OP is implying that the "`b`" byte slice contains something other than UTF-8, perhaps ASCII-7 or some 8-bit encoding such as ISO Latin-1 (e.g.). In that case OP needs to write an ISO Latin-1 (e.g.) `ToUpper()` function or OP must convert the ISO Latin-1 (e.g.) bytes to UTF-8 or unicode before using the `bytes.ToUpper()` or `unicode.ToUpper()` function.

Anything less creates a pending bug. Neither of the previously mentioned functions will properly convert all possible ISO Latin-1 (e.g.) encoded characters to upper case.

Comment: I found this method https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ToUpperSpecial for putting special unicode characters into Upper Case.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to test if an element of the board is an ASCII uppercase letter:

```
func (b Board) isUpper(x int) bool {
    v := b.board[x]
    return 'A' <= v && v <= 'Z'
}
```

If the application only needs to distinguish between upper and lowercase letters, then there's no need for the lower bound test:

```
func (b Board) isUpper(x int) bool {
    return b.board[x] <= 'Z'
}
```

The code in this answer improves on the code in the question in a few ways:

- The code in the answer returns the correct value for a board element containing 'Z' (run playground example below for demonstration).
- 'Z' and 0x85 are the same value, but the code is easier to understand with 'Z'.
- It's simpler to compare directly with the value 'Z'. No need to create a slice.

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/M66HzEHFAq)

Edit: Revamped answer based on new information in the question since time of my original answer.

Comment: And will that change the value of the byte selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bytes.ToUpper`, you just need to deal with making the input a slice,
and making the output a byte:

```
package main
import "bytes"

func main() {
   b, pos := []byte("north"), 1
   b[pos] = bytes.ToUpper(b)[pos]
   println(string(b) == "nOrth")
}
```