# How to capitalize the first letter of a string

Tags: string, go, capitalization

I have a string like this

```
var sentence string = "the biggest ocean is the Pacific ocean"
```

I want to be able to capitalize the first letter `t` in the input string, so that the string becomes

```
"The biggest ocean is the Pacific ocean"
```

How to do that in Go?

I have tried using `strings.Title` and `strings.ToTitle` however they don't do what I want.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

I have simple solution for you.

Its a fork I have of someones project on Github

https://github.com/CleanMachine1/capitalise

To use it just run in a terminal:

```sh
go mod init MODULENAME
go get github.com/cleanmachine1/capitalise
```

then in your code you can use

```golang
package main

import ("github.com/cleanmachine1/capitalise")

func main(){
 sentence = capitalise.First(sentence)
}
```

Comment: @CleanMachine1 you might have better success quoting the repo code - rather than tying a solution to a third-party package.

Answer (score 7):

**Assuming that your input string is valid UTF-8**, this thread ([Golang - ToUpper() on a single byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162102/golang-toupper-on-a-single-byte)) is close enough, though not quite a perfect duplicate. We can build on that to come to an acceptable solution using [`unicode.ToUpper`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#ToUpper) on the first **rune** of the string.

##### Most performant solution

The most performant solution (see benchmarks below) is the one suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70206760/4108803) which uses [`utf8.DecodeRuneInString`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString) although you probably want to use `ToUpper` and account for possible errors:

```
r, size := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(text)
if r == utf8.RuneError {
    // handle error
}
s = string(unicode.ToUpper(r)) + text[size:]
```

Here indexing the string with `[]` doesn't break the encoding because `size` is guaranteed to be a valid offset, according to the rune we just decoded.

##### Other solution

```
    r := []rune(s)
    r[0] = unicode.ToUpper(r[0])
    s = string(r)
```

Or with a "clever" one-liner:

```
    s := string(append([]rune{unicode.ToUpper(r[0])}, r[1:]...))
```

Unlike strings, rune slices are not immutable, so you can replace the first rune with `ToUpper`, which will take care of non-ASCII and/or multi-byte code points that do have upper cases (e.g. Russian) and leave alone those that don't (e.g. Asian scripts)

##### `ToUpper` vs. `ToTitle`

There is a difference between UPPER case and TITLE case, which is simply explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770995/difference-between-uppercase-and-titlecase). In short, digraph characters like Ǆ will have different title case (ǅ, only first grapheme capitalized) and upper cases (Ǆ, both graphemes capitalized). If you actually need titlecase, use [`unicode.ToTitle`](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode#ToTitle).

##### Large input strings

Converting `string` to/from `[]rune` involves copying, because you get a mutable slice from an immutable string. Do profile your application if you expect to use it in performance-sensitive code.

If you have a sizeable input string where a full rune slice conversion becomes too expensive, you can work around this using a capped [`strings.SplitN`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#SplitN) on some separator — or [`strings.Cut`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Cut) since later Go versions — to extract the first word of the text and use only that in the conversion:

```
sep := " "
ss := strings.SplitN(s, sep, 2)

r := []rune(ss[0])
r[0] = unicode.ToUpper(r[0])

s = string(r) + sep + ss[1])
```

##### Benchmarks

Benchmarking with a ~30K input string shows a significant difference, although the best and the second best differ by a small margin (benchmark updated with Go 1.22):

```
go test -v -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: example.com
BenchmarkRuneConv-10            6730        168665 ns/op      155648 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkSplitN-10            504634          2357 ns/op       32800 B/op          2 allocs/op
BenchmarkDecodeRune-10        533928          2307 ns/op       32768 B/op          1 allocs/op
PASS
ok      example.com 4.981s
```

With smaller strings, the `SplitN`/`Cut` solution isn't necessary and `utf8.DecodeRuneInString` is the clear winner.

A playground: https://go.dev/play/p/HpCBM7cRflZ

Comment: The previous code has a problems. For cases like `""` or `" hello"` get a panic.
So some extra code is needed
    
    `func firstLetterToUppercase(s string) string {
 sep := " "
 ss := strings.SplitN(s, sep, 2)

 r := []rune(ss[0])
 if len(r) == 0 {
  return s
 }

 r[0] = unicode.ToUpper(r[0])
 s = string(r)

 if len(ss) > 1 {
  s += sep + ss[1]
 }

 return s
    }`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve the desired result is to use `strings.ToUpper()` function. [Refer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-a-string-in-uppercase-in-golang/)

```
    var input string = "the biggest ocean is the Pacific ocean"
    res := strings.ToUpper(input[:1]) + input[1:]

    fmt.Println(res)
```

OR

You can try it on [goplayground](https://go.dev/play/p/t53SUymhh1h)

Comment: string indexing `[]` doesn't work with multi-byte input: https://go.dev/play/p/0-bi1WmC1AX

Answer (score -1):

Get the first rune, title case that rune and reassemble the string:

```
sentence := "the biggest ocean is the Pacific ocean"
r, i := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(sentence)
sentence = string(unicode.ToTitle(r)) + sentence[i:]
fmt.Println(sentence)
```

Comment: [utf8.DecodeRuneInString](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode/utf8#DecodeRuneInString) may return `RuneError` for an empty input string (or if the the start of the string has an invalid rune) - so may want to check for that.